# Prometheus Federation with Offline capabilities

Tags: prometheus

We're trying to use prometheus on machines that might go offline from time to time. Our goal is that no timestamped metric that got collected by a local prometheus instance (=same machine, guaranteed available) gets lost.

It seems the /federate endpoint will only give us the latest value of a metric, which would mean we loose all other scraped values. they exist in the time series db of the local prometheus only in this case.

Is there a an easy way yo guarantee that all collected metrics data by our local prometheus servers (even if the machine is offline from time to time) gets eventually transmitted to a collecting prometheus?

Comment: Although I understand your use case and I think it makes sense, I don't think that this is possible with Prometheus. Prometheus is a (very good!) sampling system, not a full-fledged time-series database. Federation is to make Prometheus scalable by aggregating huge samplings. Sections "When does it fit" and "When does it not fit" at https://prometheus.io/docs/introduction/overview/ give an indirect answer.